# How to use join method for a list of dictionaries and then add a string for the value

Tags: python

This is a list of dicts:

```py
list1 = [
    {'unique_id': '1qaz2wsx', 'db_id': 10},
    {'unique_id': '2qaz2wsx', 'db_id': 20},
    {'unique_id': '3qaz2wsx', 'db_id': 30},
    {'unique_id': '4qaz2wsx', 'db_id': 40},
]
```

I'm trying to have like this as expected output:

```
unique 1qaz2wsx, url http://url.com/10
unique 2qaz2wsx, url http://url.com/20
unique 3qaz2wsx, url http://url.com/30
unique 4qaz2wsx, url http://url.com/40
```

I googled for this but I couldn't find any hints up to now to how to do this. I mean I may googled the incorrect words, so I don't have any codes and attempts.

How can I have the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
list1 = [
    {'unique_id': '1qaz2wsx', 'db_id': 10},
    {'unique_id': '2qaz2wsx', 'db_id': 20},
    {'unique_id': '3qaz2wsx', 'db_id': 30},
    {'unique_id': '4qaz2wsx', 'db_id': 40},
]

output = '\n'.join([f"unique {d['unique_id']}, url http://url.com/{d['db_id']}" for d in list1])

print(output)
```

OUTPUT:

```
unique 1qaz2wsx, url http://url.com/10
unique 2qaz2wsx, url http://url.com/20
unique 3qaz2wsx, url http://url.com/30
unique 4qaz2wsx, url http://url.com/40
```

Comment: Before I ask the question. I was using `join` method but without `[]` after `()` and had errors and I didn't know why. Thanks.

Comment: @Saeed Then you should have posted your coding attempt in the question with the error messages to learn why.

Comment: @Saeed, When you call join() without the square brackets [], you're essentially trying to join the elements of a single string, not an iterable of strings. This will result in an error because the join() method expects an iterable, not a single string.

Answer (score 1):

```py
list1 = [
    {'unique_id': '1qaz2wsx', 'db_id': 10},
    {'unique_id': '2qaz2wsx', 'db_id': 20},
    {'unique_id': '3qaz2wsx', 'db_id': 30},
    {'unique_id': '4qaz2wsx', 'db_id': 40},
]

for dic in list1:  # iterate the list
    # extract keys
    uniq = dic['unique_id']
    dbid = dic['db_id']

    # format output
    print(f'unique {uniq}, url http://url.com/{dbid}')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for item in list1:
    assert len(item) >= 2, 'Item should have at least 2 keys'
    (_, unique_id), (_, db_id) = item.items()
    print(f'unique {unique_id}, url http://url.com/{db_id}')
```

References:

- https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_tuples_unpack.asp
- [https://www.datacamp.com/tutorial/role-underscore-python#:~:text=Start%20Learning-,2.%20Ignoring%20Values,-Underscore(_)](https://www.datacamp.com/tutorial/role-underscore-python#:%7E:text=Start%20Learning-,2.%20Ignoring%20Values,-Underscore(_))

Answer (score 1):

You could unpack a generator into the arguments to *print()* as follows:

```
list1 = [
    {'unique_id': '1qaz2wsx', 'db_id': 10},
    {'unique_id': '2qaz2wsx', 'db_id': 20},
    {'unique_id': '3qaz2wsx', 'db_id': 30},
    {'unique_id': '4qaz2wsx', 'db_id': 40},
]
print(*(f"unique {d["unique_id"]}, url http://url.com/{d["db_id"]}" for d in list1), sep="\n")
```

**Output:**

```
unique 1qaz2wsx, url http://url.com/10
unique 2qaz2wsx, url http://url.com/20
unique 3qaz2wsx, url http://url.com/30
unique 4qaz2wsx, url http://url.com/40
```